# The total ring of fractions of $\Bbb Z_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, localization

Consider the ring $\Bbb Z_n = \Bbb Z/n \Bbb Z$ ($n>1$, of course). Is the total ring of fractions of $\Bbb Z_n$ a familiar ring? (The total ring of fractions of a commutative ring $R$ with identity is the ring obtained from $R$ by adjoining inverses of non-zero elements of $R$ which are not zero divisors.)

I know that $\Bbb Z_p$ is a field when $p$ is prime, so that it is isomorphic to its ring of fractions. But I can't imagine what happens when $n$ is not a prime.

Comment: @SvanN I mean the "ring" of fractions. It can be defined for any nonzero commutative ring (for example, see Hungerford, chapter III.4).

Comment: **Worth emphasis:** that $\,\Bbb Z/n\,$ is already its [total ring of fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_ring_of_fractions) means that we can use familiar fraction arithmetic in these modular rings (as long as we restrict to fractions with denominator coprime to the modulus). [Many of my posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a242%20beware%20fraction) employ such modular fraction arithmetic - which often greatly simplifies calculations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In any finite commutative unital ring, all non-zero-divisors are invertible (see below). So the total ring of fractions of $\Bbb Z_n$ is $\Bbb Z_n$ itself.

Proof of above proposition: Say we have a non-zero-divisor $a\in \Bbb Z_n$. Then consider the function $\Bbb Z_n\to \Bbb Z_n$ given by multiplication by $a$. This is a group homomorphism (on the additive group $\Bbb Z_n$). Because $a$ is a non-zero-divisor, it has trivial kernel, and it is therefore injective. Since $\Bbb Z_n$ is finite, the homomorphism is also surjective, so $1$ is in the image, showing that $a$ is invertible.

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42647/rings-in-which-every-non-unit-is-a-zero-divisor